# use Java client like curl with param

Tags: java, http, curl, http-post, influxdb

I use influxdb 0.9. in this version, i can write database like

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' -d 'cpu,host=server01,region=uswest value=1.0'
```

Now I convert it to java

```
URL url = new URL("http", "localhost", 8086, "/write?db=mydb");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream wr = con.getOutputStream();
Stirng s = "cpu,host=server01,region=uswest value=51.0";
wr.write(s.getBytes(UTF_8));
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

but it doesn't work. Is the "-d" meant to represent post parameters? How can I express that in Java?

Comment: I can't test the code right now but try using URLEncoder to encode your string before posting it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Alternatively Apache HTTPClient is a bit easier to work with https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example the `curl` flag should really be `--data-binary`, not `-d`, which can have different encoding. As long as your string is unaltered by the Java code it should be fine. Anything like URL encoding will prevent the line protocol insert from working.

Comment: it is right. from make the connection to binary. `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");`

Comment: but it is always confuse me. if you want work must read the request like 'in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            in.close();' is http post only read the request can let it work?

Comment: I don't know enough Java to follow your question, my apologies. if the writes are failing, what's in the InfluxDB logs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the HTTP response as well. The following worked for me:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client {
    private static HttpURLConnection client;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Random rn = new Random();
            URL input;
            while(true) {
                input = new URL("http", "localhost", 8086, "/write?db=mydb");
                client = (HttpURLConnection) input.openConnection();
                client.setRequestMethod("POST");
                client.setDoOutput(true);

                double thermals = rn.nextDouble();
                String s = "cpu_temperature value=" + thermals;

                try (OutputStreamWriter writer =
                        new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())) {
                    writer.write(s);
                }

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                            client.getInputStream()));
                String decodedString;
                while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(decodedString);
                }
                in.close();

                System.out.println(s); // for debugging
                Thread.sleep(1000); // send data every 1 second
            }

        } catch(MalformedURLException error) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL!");
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException error) {
            System.out.println("Socket Timeout Exception!");
        } catch (IOException error) {
            System.out.println("IOException!");
            System.out.println(error);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException!");
        } finally {
            if(client != null) { // Make sure the connection is not null.
                client.disconnect();
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your SQL query need to be corrected. Remove "," in "cpu,host=" it will work.